# sum of all value but group by distinct another column

Tags: oracle

I have a question on **distinct** argument. (Or more generally in **select** argument)

I want to group by one distinct column, but in another sum column I need to sum all value. At first, I want to use the following query.

```
SELECT ZIP5,  date,   COUNT(ID), SUM(WEIGHT)

FROM ops_owner.track_mail_item

GROUP BY ZIP5, distinct (TRUNC(DATE))
```

PL/SQL development return **it is missing expression**. I know that might be because I do not using same distinct (TRUNC(DATE)) in select sentence.

However, I am do want to ID and Sum will have all value added,even if date is duplicate. **I am afraid the distinct (TRUNC(DATE)) in select sentence willl remove those duplicate record so the count/sum will be lower than what I want.**

Can any one tell me whether I can use following query to get distinct date and all sum&count value including duplicate?

```
SELECT ZIP5,  distinct (TRUNC(DATE)),   COUNT(ID), SUM(WEIGHT)

FROM ops_owner.track_mail_item

GROUP BY ZIP5, distinct (TRUNC(DATE))
```

Comment: No, you cannot use `distinct` as a function like you do.

Answer (score 3):

`DISTINCT` operates on all columns in the result set.

You do not need `DISTINCT` in your SQL - `GROUP BY` will aggregate all rows with the same `ZIP5, TRUNC(DATE)` into one.

```
SELECT ZIP5,  TRUNC(DATE),  COUNT(ID), SUM(WEIGHT)
  FROM ops_owner.track_mail_item
 GROUP BY ZIP5, TRUNC(DATE)
```

PS:
I hope you didn't really name your column `DATE`, because it is a reserved word.

Comment: So, you mean if I use the second code. The count ID and weight will be only distinct one. Count ID will be 1?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT ZIP5, TRUNC(DATE), COUNT(ID), SUM(WEIGHT)
FROM ops_owner.track_mail_item

GROUP BY ZIP5, TRUNC(DATE)
```

This will count everything, but the result will not show duplicates, as all the count and sum will of a same ZIP and DATE will be grouped together.